# Provide a browser tab icon with a base24 data URL

Tags: html

Usually to set an icon in the browser tab you use

`<link rel="icon" href="logo.png">`

I want to embed the logo in the html file using a data URL, so something like

`<link rel="icon" href="data:image/png;base64,﻿iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAzcAAALUC...">`

but it doesn't work. How can I get the base24 icon to appear in the tab.

Comment: About 12 years ago I played a game whose display area was the favicon. I'd forgotten all about that little adventure till now. http://www.p01.org/defender_of_the_favicon/

Comment: @caramba it should answer my problem, and it turns out i am actually using one of the solutions suggested, it just doesn't work in my case (in edge, chrome or firefox). I tested the base24 and it does render as an image when I use ```<img src="...">``` but does not work as an icon in ```<link rel="icon" href="...">```.

Comment: Closing this question, it turns out to be a Jinja2 problem. I am including the base24 string using Jinja2, and it fails, when I copy/paste the base24 string directly into the html it works.